# Clear cache for IIS redirect

Tags: asp.net, azure, redirect, iis, web-config

We have out .Net application deployed in Azure PaaS environment. I have updated one IIS redirect and it seems to be cache in the browser. The updated URL is not reflected in normal browser mode but works fine in incognito mode. I have tried to restart app service and even purged CDN from Azure subscription but no luck.

Status code show 301  (from disk cache) in the network tab.

Since this is production environment we can not ask every user to clear browser cache. Can I have some guidance on this please?

Comment: In short, the cache will expire (based on quite a few conditions in and/or out of your control). So what you really can do at this moment is to make sure your users can still see the right pages whether the redirection is cached or not, even if this requires your team to roll back certain changes in production environment. What's done is done and you can only plan out next production release with more caution.

Answer (score 1):

To clear client cache, you could go to **IIS Manager** -> **HTTP Response Headers** -> **Set Common Headers**(under Action pane) -> Check **Expire Web content** option.

It has 3 options.

1. Immediately
2. After(days)
3. On(in UTC)

[image]

You could select the option based on your requirement.

To clear the ARR cache, you could refer to [Delete Cached Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/delete-cached-objects)

You could try to test it and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: If we do it then it will disable/update cache settings for entire application and we need server side cache- otherwise application will go awfully slow

Comment: You could test it during the maintenance time or when there are least users using your site.